# SQL queries - process of elimination

Tags: sql

I have 3 queries that i need to put together into a single query with a single output but just cant seem to get the end result that i need. Any advice will be appreciated.

```
SampleID | TestID | Microcomments  |ProductID |ComapanyID
---------+--------+----------------+----------+----------
 111101  | Test1  | Satisfactory   | ABC123   | 1111
 111101  | Test2  | No Test        | ABC123   | 1111
 111101  | Test3  | Unsatisfactory | ABC123   | 1111
 222202  | Test2  | Satisfactory   | A21      | 2222
 222202  | Test3  | Unsatisfactory | A21      | 2222
 333301  | Test1  | Satisfactory   | AB11     | 3333
 333301  | Test3  | No Test        | AB11     | 3333
 444403  | Test2  | Unsatisfactory | ABCD123  | 4444
 444403  | Test3  | No Test        | ABCD123  | 4444
 555504  | Test1  | Unsatisfactory | BA123    | 5555
 555504  | Test2  | Unsatisfactory | BA123    | 5555
 666601  | Test3  | Satisfactory   | BBB21    | 6666
 666601  | Test2  | Satisfactory   | BBB21    | 6666
```

Query 1

```
Select distinct sample ID 
where Microcomment = 'Unsatisfactory'
```

Query 2

```
Select Distinct Sample ID 
where Microcomment = 'Satisfactory' 
  and (only display sampleID’s that don't appear in the Query 1)
```

Query 3

```
Select Distinct Sample ID 
where Microcomment = 'No Test' 
  and (only display sampleID’s that don't appear in the Query 1 & 2)
```

The final output that I'm trying to achieve

```
SampleID | Microcomments   | ProductID
---------+-----------------+----------
 111101  | Unsatisfactory  | ABC123
 222202  | Unsatisfactory  | A21
 333301  | Satisfactory    | AB11
 444403  | Unsatisfactory  | ABCD123
 555504  | Unsatisfactory  | BA123
 666601  | Satisfactory    | BBB21
```

Please note that this is not the actual data

Comment: is it possible that sample may have multiple microcomments?

Comment: those are decent and pretty straight queries that you should work it out by your own, btw which RDBMS are you using?

Comment: Is there any priority defined for microcomments? for example if sampleId has different microcomments which value should appear in final resulstset?

Comment: Your final output come from which query?

Comment: @i-man - yes the sampleid can have multiple microcomments

Comment: @long - I'm using SQL server 2012

Comment: @UsagiMiyamoto -  The final output is what i'm trying to achieve

Comment: Well, tell us then how o achieve the final result. Just because Query 3 (with the comments in parenthesis) does not produce it...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your DBMS supports it, then I think the simplest way of doing this is to rank the rows within each sample using the microcomments:

```
SELECT  SampleID, TestID, MicroComments, ProductID, CompanyID
FROM    (   SELECT  SampleID,
                    TestID,
                    MicroComments,
                    ProductID,
                    CompanyID,
                    ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY SampleID 
                                        ORDER BY CASE WHEN MicroComments = 'UnSatisfactory' THEN 1
                                                        WHEN MicroComments = 'Satisfactory' THEN 2
                                                        WHEN MicroComments = 'No test' THEN 3
                                                    END) AS RowNum
            FROM    T
        ) T
WHERE   RowNum = 1;
```

If your DBMS doesn't support it (or even if it does), you can also get this using conditional aggregates. This works on the assumption that for each SampleID the ProductID and CompanyID are constant:

```
SELECT  SampleID, ProductID, CompanyID,
        CASE WHEN COUNT(CASE WHEN MicroComments = 'UnSatisfactory' THEN 1 END) > 0 THEN 'UnSatisfactory'
            WHEN COUNT(CASE WHEN MicroComments = 'Satisfactory' THEN 1 END) > 0 THEN 'Satisfactory'
            WHEN COUNT(CASE WHEN MicroComments = 'No test' THEN 1 END) > 0 THEN 'No test'
        END AS MicroComments
FROM    T
GROUP BY SampleID, ProductID, CompanyID;
```

**[Examples on DB Fiddle](http://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2016&fiddle=3ded22f7120c67234be295d9a7a2fe15)**

Comment: This worked perfectly and fitted into my current query nicely. thank you for you input and quick support!!!!

Answer (score 1):

I think you make it more difficult than needed...

### Edited, again

Try something like these:

```sql
-- Final output:
SELECT SampleID, MAX(Microcomments), ProductID
FROM table
GROUP BY SampleID, ProductID
```

As long as it have the `Unsatisfactory`, `Satisfactory`, `No Test` values, that is alphabetically ordered and this order is the one you want to show them for a `SampleID`...

Comment: but in the resultset Microcomment can have 'Unsatisfactory' value

Comment: My question is how do i  merge query 1 2 & 3 eliminating the result with the same sampe id

Answer (score 0):

**UPDATE**

Ok, now that I better understand what you are trying to achieve, I have revised the query.

The key is to UNION the three different result sets together. Each set is created by excluding the other concerned sets using the NOT IN clause.

```
SELECT DISTINCT(t1.SampleID), t1.Microcomments, t1.ProductID
FROM t_table t1
WHERE t1.Microcomments = 'Unsatisfactory'
UNION
SELECT DISTINCT(t2.SampleID), t2.Microcomments, t2.ProductID
FROM t_table t2
WHERE t2.Microcomments = 'Satisfactory' AND t2.SampleID NOT IN (SELECT SampleID from t_table WHERE Microcomments = 'Unsatisfactory')
UNION
SELECT DISTINCT(t3.SampleID), t3.Microcomments, t3.ProductID
FROM t_table t3
WHERE t3.Microcomments = 'No Test' AND t3.SampleID NOT IN (SELECT SampleID from t_table WHERE Microcomments IN('Satisfactory','Unsatisfactory'))
ORDER BY SampleID ASC;
```

I created a sql fiddle here: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/3204f/19

Let me know if that is what you are looking for.

--Original--

You can combine all of the conditions you are searching for into a single query using OR statements in the WHERE clause. Unless the data can be more complicated than you are showing, this will work for you.

```
SELECT DISTINCT SampleID, Microcomments, ProductID
FROM table_name 
WHERE Microcomments = ‘Satisfactory’ OR Microcomments = ‘Satisfactory’ OR Microcomments = ‘No Test’ 
ORDER BY Microcomments
```

Comment: This would return all the data, without eliminating any duplicate sample id's

Comment: @KAI, I have updated the response based on a better understanding of the issue

Comment: the updated query has also worked. thank you for taking the time and the support !!! sorry i'm unable to mark it up as a useful responce as my rep is under 15